# Error:(122, 21) No resource found that matches the given name:

Tags: android

I am trying to develop an application that mainly support the JellyBean and KitKat Version.

I have downloaded all the APIs necessary and am trying to compile my code from the older API ( 19.1.0 ) . But I get some errors and automatically the values ​​- values-v21.xml and values-v23.xml opens. What should I do?

```
C:\Users\lf_fr_000\AndroidStudioProjects\AppSicit2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'.
    C:\Users\lf_fr_000\AndroidStudioProjects\AppSicit2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Theme.Material.Light'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'.

    (...)

    C:\Users\lf_fr_000\AndroidStudioProjects\AppSicit2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\res\values-v23\values-v23.xml
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
    Error:(2) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.

    Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
    > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Users\lf_fr_000\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\19.1.0\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

My Module Settings:

```
Compile Sdk Version = API 19 4.4 (KitKat)
Build Tools Version = 19.1.0
```

My Gradle Settings:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.fronchetti.appsicit"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Please check my answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**@Felipe Fronchetti**

### Whats your logcat throws

```
C:\Users\lf_fr_000\AndroidStudioProjects\AppSicit2\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.0.1\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
```

Actually **compileSdkVersion** gives your app access to the newest APIs, styles and themes. You will have a compilation error if you try to use an API introduced in a more recent Android version than **compileSdkVersion**.

So basically , Please update your `compileSdkVersion` level ,
You are using `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'` so update your `compileSdkVersion` and `buildToolsVersion`.

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"
```

**Finally**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.fronchetti.appsicit"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your compile SDK version must match the support library's major version.And target sdkVersion should match the compileSdk Version.The final code like that

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '19.1.0'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.fronchetti.appsicit"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
}
```

Hope that solve your problem.